# Phase difference in SHM between spatial coordinate and velocity

Tags: velocity, harmonic-oscillator

In simple harmonic motion the spatial coordinate $x(t)$ and the velocity $v(t)$ have a phase difference of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and I'm totally ok with that. But I also saw that the difference in the phase can be expressed as $\frac{\tau}{4}$, where $\tau$ is the period of the motion. I cannot see the reason of this, why can we say that $\frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{\tau}{4}$?

Comment: You can't. One refers to a phase in the "angle" domain and one refers to a phase in the time domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Harmonic motion is sinusoidal: $x(t)=x_0\sin(ωt)=x_0\sin(2πt/τ)$. The argument of the sine function is called *phase*, here an increasing funtion of time: $x(t)=x_0\sin(φ(t))$ with $φ(t)=ωt=2πt/τ$.

Hence, a phase difference $δφ$ corresponds to a time difference $δt=δφ/ω=δφ\,τ/2π$. With $δφ=π/2$ you find $δt=τ/4$.

Remember: $1\ \text{period} ↔ 2π ↔ τ$